# Three20 dependency problem

Tags: iphone, three20, circular-dependency

I checked out the three20 source and was trying to follow this
[guide](http://www.three20.info/tutorials/github) to build an iphone app using the framework. Within this guide, Templates are used which I checked out too. They ought to compile properly, but I get the following error:

File /Users/myUser/programming/three20/src/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a depends on itself.  This target might include its own product.

Did anyone ever solve that issue? I read it was about including something you want to create which is not possible. Anyway any solution I found did not help here.

I actually did not even change anything! Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, I just found out, this now happens every time, I try to include the three20 lib into any project. Before installing the Templates mentioned above, at least that worked. Any1 have any clue?

Comment: I can add, that if I remove the XCode 320 project from my newly created project, then at least it starts to compile, but I get Linker errors instead.... I guess that doesnt help much? :)

Comment: I get the same error whenever including it (using the same instructions), as well as building the .xcodeproj in three20/src. Would love to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I fixed this by opening the three20.xcodeproj and unchecking the target box for libThree20.a (while leaving it checked in my project that is using three20).

This has at least got me building and running, will report if any problems come up later.